# argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads mapKit

Tags: ios, swift2, mkmapview

```
let mapView = MKMapView((MKMapView, didAddAnnotationViews: [MKAnnotationView]))
```

This is my code and I don't understand why I'm getting this error. The error is on the `M` in the first `MKMapView`. I don't understand what to do.

I am trying to make a mapView, and put locations on the map.

Comment: Why are you still using Swift 2. It's done. You need to migrate to Swift 3 (and soon Swift 4).

Comment: MapView have 3 initializers  `let mapView = MKMapView()`  or `let mapView = MKMapView(coder: <#T##NSCoder#>)` or  `let mapView = MKMapView(frame: <#T##CGRect#>) ` you are calling an initializer that don´t exist

Comment: did my answer helped?